# How to run kvm/qemu on a virtual terminal with kms enabled

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, kms, sdl, framebuffer

I deduce from the kvm howtos that this should actually work with sdl and a framebuffer, but I can't get it going.
Doing `kvm -cdrom tinycore-current.iso` with normal user account on a virtual terminal gives:

```
kvm: pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-rtl8139.bin"
init kbd.
init mouse failed.
Could not initialize SDL(Unable to open mouse) - exiting
```

While it works flawlessly under X.

Running it with `sudo` prepended crashes display and keyboard.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, SDL cannot access the mouse. If this error doesn't show as root (using `sudo`), this is probably a permissions problem. You should check the permissions of `/dev/input/mice`.

It is likely that once the mouse problem is fixed it will show the same behaviour as when run using `sudo`. It might not be worth the trouble to try getting it running with framebuffer. Without knowing the details I'd say using X might a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

First issue :

means you have no pxe bootrom images installed. try installing them, or look them up in `/usr/share/qemu` or `/usr/share/gpxe`

```
sudo apt-file search pxe-rtl8139.bin
```

says that this file is in the kvm-pxe package. So will fix your problem.

```
sudo aptitude install kvm-pxe
```

2nd Issue

If SDL is complaining because it can't find any mouse (Unable to init SDL: Unable to open mouse) then, before launching the program, do:

```
export SDL_NOMOUSE=1
```